# How do I install Imagick for PHP?

Tags: php

I am so confused right now, I have no idea what to do. I want to use Imagciks function but I have NO IDEA HOW. I'm really frustrated because I've never seen something that makes no sense to me. I can't even find a good explanation!

Comment: Can you post some details about your OS/environment?

Comment: Uhh, I'm using Windows, and I have someone else hosting my server.

Comment: If you're using a shared host you may be out of luck. But contact your host administrators and see if they can help you out.

Comment: Ok, I can host it myself if I needed to though.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you *must* have root on the machine.

First, [install the requirements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.requirements.php).  If you are on Linux, your distro almost certainly has Image Magick available in the package repository.  You'll need both the binaries and the development project.

Second, you need to [use PECL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php) (PHP's binary extension manager) to [install the extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php).  It will automatically compile it and install it for you.

Third, you'll need to make sure it's been installed properly by checking php.ini, then restart your web server software.  You should then have the extension available to you.

If you don't have root, you're out of luck.  You will need to ask your host about installing it.  Note that they may be more amenable to the idea of installing *just* Image Magick itself instead of it and the PHP extension.  Image Magick is actually centered around [a group of command line programs](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php?ImageMagick=r6v0durioqeesttpt5h0gs6sh2) that you can call from your PHP script *without* the extension.

It is worth noting that all of this information [is available in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).  I would *highly suggest* reading through the manual first if you have any further questions.

---

Edit: Oops, missed the fact that you're on Windows.  I don't know if the extension *can* be built on Windows.  You'll probably need to [just grab the command line programs pre-built for Windows](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) and call them the oldschool way.